# Apple push notifications not working for testflight build

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, apn

So I have a app uploaded to `testFlight` and i am trying to send `push notification` to all the users. Some of the users are getting the notification and some are not. So i tried using a third party tool(Pusher) to send push notification. But still i get the same error

> "apn invalid token".

I have checked the code many times the token is correct.**Also even if I use the same token, sometimes it gets the notification and some times it says invalid token.**  I know these question has been asked but none of them answers my case because the token is not expired also certificates are properly created.
[image]

Comment: Strange case.... !

Comment: You have to use Production environment for TestFlight since the TestFlight build is release one.